# random.choice and raise in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I need to write a function that throws one of the three exceptions randomly:
ValueError, TypeError or RuntimeError. In the place of the function call, handle all three exceptions.
How i understood, i need to 'raise' one of the Exception, but i dont understood how 'raise' can work with 'random.choice'. Can you help me? Thank's for your answer.

```
def function1 ():
    try:
        import random
        raise random.choiсe([ValueError('Error1'), TypeError('Error2'), RuntimeError('Error3')])
    except ValueError:
        print ('Wrong Value!')
    except TypeError:
        print ('Wrong Type!')
    except RuntimeError:
        print ('Runtime Error!')
```

Comment: What happens if you run your code?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to accomplish. The problem with your code is that you are raising all three errors whereas you meant to raise just one, randomly. Here is one approach:

```
errors = [
    (ValueError, 'Error1'),
    (TypeError, 'Error2'),
    (RuntimeError, 'Error3')
]
error, message = random.choice(errors)

try:
    raise error(message)
```

Notes

- `errors` is a list of tuples, each tuple denotes an error and a message
- The `random.choice()` call then select one of these error and message
- Now, it is a matter of raising that error

Comment: No, the questioners code creates three Exception objects but only raises one.

Comment: @HaiVu thank you! Now i understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

As best I could interpret this, You could use `int(choice(lst))` and choose from `'a'(ValueError), [1, 2, 3](TypeError)` to randomly throw the first two errors and then you can `raise` your `RuntimeError`

```
from random import choice
lst = ['a', [1, 2, 3]]

def handler(x):
    try:
        a = int(choice(lst))
    except TypeError:
        print('Type Error')
    except ValueError:
        print('Value Error')
    raise RuntimeError('Runtime Error')

handler(lst)
```

> ```
> Value Error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "vash.py", line 13, in <module>
>     handler(lst)
>   File "vash.py", line 11, in handler
>     raise RuntimeError('Runtime Error')
> RuntimeError: Runtime Error
> ```